# javascript - Trigger event when any checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript

In my HTML, I have a lot of checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox"> Check me! 
<input type="checkbox"> Check me as well!
<input type="checkbox"> Check me too! 
<input type="checkbox"> This is a checkbox.
<input type="checkbox"> It is not a radio button.  
<input type="checkbox"> Just saying.  

(Even more checkboxes ..............)
```

Without jQuery, how do I create an alert once any checkbox in the document is changed?

(With so many checkboxes, it will be very troublesome to add `onclick="alert('Hello!');"` on every single checkbox.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you would do it without jQuery:

```
// get all the checkboxes on the page
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

// add a change event listener
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        console.log('the checkbox changed');
    });
}
```

Note: `document.querySelectorAll` is not supported in IE7 or below.

http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Answer (score 2):

Clicks are bubbling through the document, you could use a single eventlistener for the parent element of these `input`s. Something like this:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="checkbox"> Check me!
    <input type="checkbox"> Check me as well!
    <input type="checkbox"> Check me too!
    <input type="checkbox"> This is a checkbox.
    <input type="checkbox"> It is not a radio button.
    <input type="checkbox"> Just saying.
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
        alert('Checkbox');
    }
});
```

If you don't have a `form` or any other common parent element (and you don't want to add a one), you can add the listener to the `document` as well.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5zN5/).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /> Check me!
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/> Check me as well!
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/> Check me too!
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/> This is a checkbox.
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/> It is not a radio button.
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/> Just saying.
</form>
```

JS:

```
var cbobject= document.forms[0].elements.checkbox;
for (var i=0, len=cbobject.length; i<len; i++) {
        if ( cbobject[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
            cbobject[i].onclick = show_alert;
        }
    }
function show_alert(e){
    alert("checkbox!!!")
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/88mLN/)**: